# Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module - UnicodeDecodeError - Not able to run any script in python from command prompt

Tags: python

I am not able to run any script in python. Getting following error.

```
C:\Python33>jupyter notebook
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\site.py", line 579, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site.py", line 349, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site.py", line 163, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "c:\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 642: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: This error has a lot of existing solutions online, please specify which ones you've tried so we don't have to waste our time trying to figure out what you have and haven't already attempted. If you haven't tried anything, then please try _everything you can_ before posting here, which you're supposed to have done (see "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251)" for why).

Comment: Most of the error questions asked online are related to problem running a code in python. Here I am not able to do anything in python. This hasnt been asked by anyone.

Comment: My best guess is that your Python installation is screwed up. Reinstall Python, and while you're at it, install a supported version (3.6 is the oldest currently supported 3.x version).